# How to convert an array of Booleans to a string representation?

Tags: python, arrays, python-2.7, hash

I'd like to convert [imagehash](https://pypi.org/project/ImageHash/) array of booleans like this:

```
array([[False, False, False,  True, False, False,  True,  True],
       [False, False, False,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True],
       [False,  False, False,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True],
       [False,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True],
       [False,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True, False, False],
       [False,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True, False],
       [False, False,  True, False, False, False,  True, False],
       [False, False, False, False, False, False,  True,  True]]))
```

To a string representation like `94b1b9fcfcfcf0f0`  and vice versa using Python 2.7.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: How would the hex number(s) look like for the above array?

Comment: Something like `94b1b9fcfcfcf0f0`. Basically I'd like to encode/decode hashes of https://pypi.org/project/ImageHash/ to strings, so that I can save them to database.

Comment: are you looking for something like this ?

`hex(int(''.join(list(map(lambda arr: ''.join(map(lambda bin: '1' if bin else '0', arr)), a))), 2))`

replace **a** with you array name.

Comment: @ruhaib I get this error: `argument 2 to map() must support iteration`

Comment: did you replace "a" with your array variable ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following code converts your Boolean values to 0/1 and gets the hexadecimal values from those numbers (8 binary digits gives a maximum of 2 hexadecimal characters (from 00 to ff). `zfill` is used to fill the left zero if the number is smaller than 128. `[2:]` strips the hexadecimal representation (`0x`).

```
hexstring = "".join([str(hex(int("{}".format("".join(["1" if elem else "0" for elem in line])), 2)))[2:].zfill(2) for line in array])
print(hexstring)
```

P.S. this solution implies pure Python only - `array` variable holds a list of lists:

```
array = [
    [False, False, False, True, False, False, True, True],
    [False, False, False, True, True, True, True, True],
    [False, False, False, True, True, True, True, True],
    [False, True, True, True, True, True, True, True],
    [False, True, True, True, True, True, False, False],
    [False, True, True, True, True, True, True, False],
    [False, False, True, False, False, False, True, False],
    [False, False, False, False, False, False, True, True],
]
```

Comment: I get this error: `'ImageHash' object is not iterable`

Comment: How to save the output to a value?

Comment: Check another edit, `hexstring` variable is created.

Comment: I still get `'ImageHash' object is not iterable`. Please notice that the array is the output of  `hash = imagehash.average_hash(img)`

Comment: Have you tried converting that output to string with `str(output)`?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/198201/discussion-between-milkyway-and-ipaleka).